# Error code 3 : Invalid value: configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts

Tags: google-bigquery

Since Google updated Bigquery a couple of days ago i've met a problem with scheduled queries.
Usually i use them to update different tables with the new data every day.

So in my queries i write 'insert into *table* select data from previous day'

Some queries are complex and i update tables in a loop adding rows several time.

But now i can't do it and got an error - 'Error code 3 : Invalid value: configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts;'

How can i fix it?

**UPD**. We found out that Google changed the innterface not for everyone, but for some users, and we are among them.
If you meet such problems, just switch to the old interface by pressing "Hide preview features" at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Clink <kbd>More</kbd> then <kbd>Query Settings</kbd>

[image]

Inside settings - check Destination as below

[image]

... and finally <kbd>Save</kbd> settings

Comment: Where to search for temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem.
Google update Bigquery and there is no other option.
I must add some table for target.
If I don't add table name then I can't update scheduled query.
"Error code 3 : Invalid value: configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts"

Update: Check this link. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178013742
They say "Hide Preview Features" in the BigQuery console.
I also try it. And **It works**.